# Updating the data in Firebase deletes the old child and replaces it USING SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I try to add data to the Firebase database in swift, instead of adding a new child, it deletes the old one and replaces it. Here's my swift code:

```
func wordsAdd() {

        newRef = Database.database().reference()
        newRef?.child("wordList").child("\(wordTypePicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0))").child("category").setValue(wordTypeSelection)
        newRef?.child("wordList").child("\(wordTypePicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0))").child("categoryID").setValue(wordTypePicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0))
        newRef?.child("wordList").child("\(wordTypePicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0))").child("words").setValue(wordListArray)

    }
```

Here's the Firebase data structure: 
[image]

What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `newRef?.updateChildValues(post)` ?

Comment: Can you please explain what is the return value of `\(wordTypePicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0))`

Comment: @Vishal16 this returns the index number of the selection made of the word category in a PickerView. For example, I have 8 categories in a pickerView. I am using the index value of the category as the word category's unique ID. So a selection of the second item in the picker view will return a value of '3'. Did this make things clearer?

Comment: @BoldLion, it doesn't let me put (post) as a value for updateChildValues. How would I do it?

Comment: There’s nothing in that code that ‘adds’ new data. It will overwrite the existing data each time you run it. What is the old vs new data

Comment: @Jay the old child is the one that currently exists in the database. When I implement the wordsAdd() method, it overwrites the 'old' child. Does this makes things clearer?

Comment: I understand the code. However, the code presented in the question doesn't create a new node, it simply keeps overwriting the same node. e.g. this code `.child("\(wordTypePicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0))")` is always 0, so that's the node that is written to. Typically, you would use .childByAutoId to create a key for a new node and then the new data would be child nodes of that key. Also, if you're planning on using an array to store your data, don't. Arrays are generally not a good fit for NoSQL databases.

Comment: @Jay the inComponent property of the pickerView refers to the column in the Picker View. In my case, I just have one column and hence it'll remain 0 throughout. The ROW, however, depends on the user and hence I called the .selectedRow() method.

Comment: My apologies, I was unclear. I see what you are trying to do - however, that *appears* to be returning a value of 0, so that's the node that's being written. Test it by adding `let x = wordTypePicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)` and then `print(x)` to see if that is returning 0 each time. Also, you should avoid array's in the first place see [Arrays Are Evil](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html)

Comment: Hey @Jay. I tried this and it is not returning 0 every time. It's returning different values for different categories selected in the pickerView. Also, Thanks for linking the article. It made some good point. What should I do instead? The article mentions to use autoID but I am hesitant to do that because it'll be much more complicated to pull data from the database. What are your suggestions? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: well, if its returning something other than 0, then those nodes would be created e.g. wordList/0/... and then wordList/1/..., wordList/2/... If I run that exact code in my project, those are the nodes that are created.

Comment: @Jay Correct. That is happening with my code as well. The problem, however, is that the node inside of the ' words' node gets replaced by any other word node I create.

Comment: Well, you are writing an array and in Firebase, array's cannot be modified. They need to be re-written. I would suggest not using arrays as per my comment and link in an above comment. You may want to test what's in the array... You may also want to clarify the question as it wasn't clear which node was being overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

```
func addWords() {
    let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "wordList")
    let word: NSArray = [wordTextField.text!] // Watch out with force unwrapping here better to use guard
    let post =
            [
                "category": wordTypeSelection
                "categoryID": categoryID
                "words" : word
                ] as [String : Any]
    print(post)
    ref.child("0").setValue(post) // If you know in which node you have to put the data

    // or

    ref.updateChildValues(post) // To update every child
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Stijnk008. I tried doing this but it still replaces the old word. I tried writing the code differently. It would be great if you could take a look at the edited question. The edited question code also, however, replaces the original child. Please let me know what I can do. Thanks